# Physics2D simulation is not taking into acount the material's Friction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I'm currently working in a 2d ball game and I need to show the trajectory of the ball before being thrown. To achieve that, I clone my scene and run a simulation using `PhysicsScene2D.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime)` The problem is that the simulation is not taking into consideration the lost of momentum due to the friction during the collisions and it's not accurate. I realized that if I set the friction of the ball to 0, or if I disable the rotation in the Z axis from the rigidbody2D, the simulation is completely accurate. Unfortunately, I need to have friction and I need the simulation to work with it, is it possible?

I'm using Unity 2020.3.29f1

[image: The dotted line is the calculated trajectory, the solid line is the actual movement of the ball.]

I have modified the physics materials and tried to call the simulation in different updates (Normal Update, Fixed Update and Late Update) and using Time.DeltaTime and Time.FixedDeltaTime but nothing seems to make a difference.

Comment: Hi! Can you please share your `FixedUpdate` method? I would also be nice to see the values you have to member variables used in your method.

Comment: I found that the problem was being caused because I was resetting the inertia of the ball to 0. After removing that part form the code everything is working fine.